# Can't import longitude and latitude into phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin

I have a file with a list of store names and addresses, phone, and longitude and latitude. When I import the file using phpMyAdmin it loads everything just fine EXCEPT for the longitude and latitude fields. For these fields, a few load but most do not. I've tried using CSV and XML. I've looked over these files for anything strange like quotes where they shouldn't be etc. but haven't found anything. The field type in the DB is float (10,6). If it helps, here are the 2 files:

http://eyesbryte.com/StoreList-editedCorrect3.txt

http://eyesbryte.com/StoreList-editedCorrect.xml

Can anyone please help before I pull out all my hair?

Comment: It would help if you showed us what you're trying to load these values into.  The latitude & longitude values have two `.` delimiters in, so they won't load into a numeric field.

Comment: Can you just try and check if it help you. Change longitude and latitude field type from `double` to `float` or vice-versa

Comment: The field type is float (10,6)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the thousands separator `.` in both fields.

In order to properly store values for `latitude` and `longitude` represented in decimal degrees, you must have two `decimal` data-type fields. Decimal fields doesn't allow thousands separator.